# How to fetch new emails in Gnus

Tags: gnus, email

I've not used Gnus in a long time, but, if my memory serves, simply opening a group would check for new emails and fetch them.  For some reason this doesn't happen anymore... I can, however, tell it to fetch old emails.  And, if I kill Gnus buffer and load it again, it does fetch the new emails.

So... how do I do this without killing the buffer and restarting Gnus?

PS. I'm connected to IMAP server, so, I'd expect this to be something really basic...

Comment: The commande gnus-group-get-new-news don't fetch new news ?

Comment: @gigiair nope, that seems to do nothing.

Comment: does the command gnus-group-enter-server-mode show the IMAP server open ?

Comment: I think this is the relevant output of this command: `{nnimap:outlook} (opened)` (there are two more similar outputs, but they both say "opened" and they seem not to be related to the external server.